# How to use `tabularx` including rule with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`?

Tags: tabularx, xparse

The following MWE gives me a `Misplaced \noalign.` error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytabular}{}{\tabularx{\linewidth}{XX}}{\bottomrule\endtabularx}
%\newenvironment{mytabular}{\tabularx{\linewidth}{XX}}{\bottomrule\endtabularx} % this does not throw an error

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{mytabular}
a & b\\
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

Switching the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` with `\newenvironment` or removing the `\bottomrule` gets rid of the error, but I would like to use the improved argument syntax in the actual (not minimized) code without having the include the `\bottomrule` every time. I'm guessing the issue is with how `tabularx` captures the table body, but is there a way to make this work?

Comment: afaik `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is not from `etoolbox` but from `xparse`, which is now (since October 2020) integrated in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `+b` argument type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytabular}{+b}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    #1
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
}{}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{mytabular}
a & b\\
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For information, you can try `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which has its own system of `X` columns. You have directly the expected behaviour with the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytabular}{}{\begin{NiceTabular}{XX}}{\bottomrule\end{NiceTabular}}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{mytabular}
a & b\\
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

The reason is that `{NiceTabular}` does not catch its body as a TeX argument because the successives compositions of the tabular (in order to compute the width of the `X` columns) are done with successive compilations of the whole document (and informations written on the `aux` file). Of course, the main drawback is that requires several compilations.